# How do I unit test the querydsl query inside the given method?

Tags: java, jpa, junit, junit4, querydsl

```
public UserEntity findUserByUsername( String username ) {

    QUserEntity tableUser = QUserEntity.userEntity;

    JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery( entityManager )
        .from( tableUser )
        .where( tableUser.ds_username.eq( username ) );

    return ( UserEntity ) query.singleResult( tableUser );
}
```

Using the last version of junit.

Comment: Do you want to test the method without a database connection?

Comment: Yes, the intention here would be unit test and not integration test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could mock the `EntityManager` and verify that Querydsl uses the `EntityManager` in the way you anticipated.

Comment: I suppose that would be the only way then. If I rely in the way querydsl manipulates the entityManager I will not get any surprises on any upcoming querydsl updates, am I? I am not sure if this is the safest way to go, if this is not, I will end up delegating this to integration tests.

Comment: If you want to test the internal logic of Querydsl then unit testing with a mocked EntityManager is the way ok. If you just want to make sure that your findUserByUsername method works then integration testing would be a better choice.